# Consulting multiple knowledge bases but keeping the data separate

Tags: module, prolog

Suppose I have two sets of atoms, each of which is kept in a separate file (say `f1` and `f2`). What I want to do is define a query: `p(X,Res)` such that `p(X,yes)` if `X` is an atom in `f1` and `p(X,maybe)` if `X` is in `f2`.

Is this a case where modules could be used?

Comment: "atoms" in a file? Are they rules suitable for https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=consult/1 , or needing some parsing?

Comment: They’re prolog atoms - ground atoms to be more specific (i.e., no variables)

Comment: I didn’t use consult because the providence matters. Meaning I need to know which of the knowledge bases is being used.

Comment: If it helps - I’m trying to use prolog as a wrapper around the asp solver clingo to enable me to answer complex queries about the brave and cautious consequences of a program

Comment: Can parse the files using a DCG - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=phrase_from_file/2 and then save the data in whatever format you want, using https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=assert/1